# Plot crosses on time axis for a binary dependent variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, time, binary

I want to use ggplot2 to plot a binary variable over time, such that whenever we observe the event (y = 1) for a given individual (id), there is a cross (or point) on the x-axis.

Here is some data:

```
access <- rbinom(n=500,size=1,prob=0.40)
id <- rep(1:10, each = 50)   
day_id <- rep(1:50, 10)
da <- data.frame(access = access, id = id, day_id = day_id)
```

Currently I'm using ggplot2 in the following way:

```
  da %>% ggplot(aes(x = day_id, y = access)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~id)
```

This leads to this result:
[image: Result ggplot2]

But I want it to look like this (with crosses or points reflecting whether there was access; and the x_axis reflecting a sequence of 50 days per individual):
[image: Target plot]

Where each line represents one id.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Sure, I have added some data, sorry.

Comment: What's the x-axis in your desired figure?

Comment: The x_axis represents time, in my example data it is day_id, so the number of days since the first observation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

da %>% ggplot(aes(x = day_id, y = factor(id))) + 
  geom_point(data=filter(da, access==1)) +
  geom_line() + 
  labs(y="id") + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Is there a way to show crosses instead of points?

Comment: Yes - you can add `shape=4` to the `geom_point` aesthetic

Comment: `geom_point(data=filter(da, access==1), shape=4)`

Answer (score 2):

```
Points

uid <- unique(da$id)

plot.new()
plot.window(c(0, nrow(da[da$id == uid[1], ])), c(1, length(uid)))
for (i in seq_along(uid)) {
  y <- with(da, access[id == uid[i]])
  points(seq_along(y), rep.int(length(uid) - i + 1L, length(y)), col=y, pch=20)
  lines(seq_along(y), rep.int(length(uid) - i + 1L, length(y)), lwd=1.5)
} 
mtext(LETTERS[rev(seq_along(uid))], 2, at=seq_along(uid), las=1)
```

[image]

*Crosses*

```
plot.new()
plot.window(c(0, nrow(da[da$id == uid[1], ])), c(1, length(uid)))
for (i in seq_along(uid)) {
  y <- with(da, access[id == uid[i]])
  points(seq_along(y), rep.int(length(uid) - i + 1L, length(y)), col=y, pch=3)
  lines(seq_along(y), rep.int(length(uid) - i + 1L, length(y)), lwd=1.5)
} 
mtext(LETTERS[rev(seq_along(uid))], 2, at=seq_along(uid), las=1)
```

[image]

*Alternative visualization*

```
split(da$access, da$id) |> rev() |> do.call(what='cbind') |> image(col=0:1, axes=FALSE) +
  mtext(LETTERS[rev(unique(da$id))], 2, 1, at=seq.int(0, 1, length.out=length(unique(da$id))), las=1) + box()
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
access <- rbinom(n=500,size=1,prob=0.40)
id <- rep(1:10, each=50)   
day_id <- rep.int(1:50, 10)
da <- data.frame(access=access, id=id, day_id=day_id)
```

Comment: Love the alternative visualisation!